# Ubuntu shows incorrect Thai language with 'ls' command

Tags: files, filesystem, 19.10, locale, putty

Ubuntu shows filenames in Thai language incorrectly.

[image]

```
$ locale
LANG=th_TH.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE= 
LC_CTYPE="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_TIME="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_NAME="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_ADDRESS="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_TELEPHONE="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_MEASUREMENT="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_IDENTIFICATION="th_TH.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL=  

$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8 
en_US.utf8 
POSIX 
th_TH.utf8
```

Comment: Take a note, that you are using putty's terminal. Maybe it is not ubuntu's issue but putty's

Comment: Also, show us what locales do you have: `locale` and `locale -a` commands outputs are desirable.

Comment: In which configuration file did you set `LANG` to `th_TH.UTF-8`?

Answer (score 0):

1. As suggested in one of [this question's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25350/working-with-filenames-in-a-different-encoding-over-ssh?rq=1) answer:

> Inside a terminal emulator that supports UTF-8, you can use the luit
>   command to run a subshell (or other program) in a different locale.
>   The locale setting that indicates character sets is LC_CTYPE.
>
> ```
> LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.KOI8-R luit ls   # run one command
> LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.KOI8-R luit      # start a shell (type Ctrl+D or exit to return to the parent shell)
> ```

2. You could try to set for your putty's session:

   `PuTTY Configuration
       Session
           Window
               Translation
                   Remote character set: UTF-8`

   [image: putty's encoding settings]
3. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/660514/521673) suggests to change *`Connection` > `Data` > `Terminal-type string` to `putty` instead of `xterm`*.
4. Changing your locale is suggested [in this guide](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-set-up-system-locale-on-ubuntu-16-04/):

   ```
   sudo update-locale LANG=<name of locale here>

   user@ubuntu:~/ $ cat /etc/default/locale 
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   user@ubuntu:~/ $ sudo update-locale LANG=uk_UA.utf8
   [sudo] password for user: 
   user@ubuntu:~/ $ cat /etc/default/locale 
   LANG=uk_UA.utf8
   ```

In your case you could use `th_TH.UTF-8`

In my case putty displays Thai's encoding correctly even with `xterm` in `Terminal-type string` parameter:
[image: putty's thai symbols]

Locale in windows:

> Current language for non-Unicode programs: English (United States)

5. Try putty's [alternatives](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/best-putty-alternatives-ssh-clients/).

**Update:** We've tried to create a file with a name in Thai's encoding and it is displayed as expected - in Thai's encoding. But old file with name in Thai's encoding is displayed incorrectly. So we suggested the issue could be with how ftp server processes files in Thai's encoding.

6. Take a note what program or service writes changes to disk and how it encodes symbols in files' names with your encoding.